# How to prevent echo of previous line when using kotlin interactive shell?

Tags: shell, kotlin

First, I downloaded the Windows Command Line tools for Kotlin on Windows 10. (https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/releases/tag/v1.2.30)

Then, I start the interactive shell thinking that it works like the Python interactive shell, and I can use it to type in code examples:

```
C:\MyFolder> C:\kotlinc\bin\kotlinc.bat
Welcome to Kotlin version 1.2.30 (JRE 1.8.0_162-b12)
Type :help for help, :quit for quit
>>>
```

However, when I type this code interactively into kotlinc:

```
fun stuff() {
    println("Hello, World")
}
```

It echos the previous line when I hit return. For Example:

```
>>> fun stuff() {
fun stuff()... println("Hello, World")
println("Hello, World")... }
}>>>
>>>
>>> stuff()
stuff()Hello, World
```

Is there anyway to prevent kotlin from echoing the previous line that I entered interactively, particularly for multiline statements?

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin interactive mode works correctly inside of Android Studio.

From a Kotlin Project, Open the Kotlin REPL console:

Tools->Kotlin REPL

Comment: Not sure whether it's version-related, but this REPL console becomes *very* slow after a few commands and gets unusable pretty quickly, so it might not be a replacement (provided the OP uses Android Studio or another IDE from Jetbrains in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

This is a confirmed bug, there is no sure way to prevent this echo until a fix is released:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23615
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22990